# Azure Devops CLI Task - show output

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am using the Azure CLI task Version 2. The only problem, i need some output so that it´s showed as part of the pipeline run. The task however wraps all inline scripts in a script file so that i can´t see the output. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Welcome! This question is too broad. What do you want to see? If the task is hiding too much then you could go for a try using the PowerShell step. Add more context please.

Comment: Sorry for that. I run some kubectl commands as the built in task are not working for what I try to achieve. The output is a json string (external public IP) i want to see in the logfile output

Comment: Could you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? The Azure CLI is used to run arbitrary Azure commands. Most likely you should instead use a task such as `CmdLine@2` or `PowerShell@2`  as Alexander suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. It works now, you are right, I used the Bash@3 task instead. I use the output from the AzCLI task to define a pipeline variable and the bash task to print it.

```
service=$(kubectl get service --namespace $(aks-namespace) -o jsonpath='{.items[0].status.loadBalancer.ingress[0]}')
   echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=serviceip]$service"
```